# Why geometry package cause margin overflow with Babel finnish?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, accents

Code which I execute with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{report} 
\usepackage{geometry}    
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}

\begin{document}
Toisen vaiheen jatkotukimuksena voi olla, miten temporaali-ilmi\"{o}t, kuten s\"{a}hk\"{o}verkon h\"{a}iri\"{o}t, n\"{a}kyv\"{a}t signaaleissa. 
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, 
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output is wrong with the geometry package where first line passes the margin, 
Fig. 2 Output is correct without geometry package

[image]
[image]

OS: Debian 8.5
TexLive: 2016

Comment: Nothing to do with geometry, also happens without

Comment: Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Without `geometry` the word is not at the edge of the text, so you don't notice that it cannot be hyphenated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that makes precomposed accented characters available. Without it, TeX builds the accents and is unable to hyphenate past them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}

\begin{document}
Toisen vaiheen jatkotukimuksena voi olla, miten temporaali-ilmi\"{o}t, kuten s\"{a}hk\"{o}verkon h\"{a}iri\"{o}t, n\"{a}kyv\"{a}t signaaleissa. 
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, miten ...
Oppilasty\"{o} on tapaustutkimus siit\"{a}, 
\end{document}
```

[image]